# BizTalk - Catch pipeline Exception. Exception Message gets truncated.

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations

Please have a look at below response in Postman :

“

    
        http://www.xyz.co.uk/ABC/schema/ophthalmicpayments/GOS:Title' element has an invalid value according to its data type.
The 'http://www.xyz.co.uk/ABC/schema/ophthalmicpayments/GOS:DOB' element has an invalid value according to its data type.
The 'http://www.xyz.co.uk/ABC/schema/ophthalmicpayments/GOS:PostCode' element has an invalid value according to its data type.
The 'http://www.xyz.co.uk/ABC/schema/ophthalmicpayments/GOS:NHSNumber' element has an invalid value according to its data type.
The 'http://www.xyz.co.uk/ABC/schema/ophthalmicpayments/GOS:NINumber' element has an invalid value according to its data type.
The 'http://www.xyz.co.uk/ABC/schema/ophthalmicpayments/GOS:Last-Sight-Test' element has an invalid value according to its data type.
The 'http://www.xyz.co.uk/ABC/schema/ophthalmicpayments/GOS:Eligibility-Evidence' element has an invalid value according to its data type.
The 'http://www.xyz.co.uk/ABC/schema/ophthalmicpayments/GOS:Patient' *****element has an inva...".**"*** />
    
”

Messaga after  - element has an inva is truncated.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the expected behavior.  Validation errors can be very long and it's often impractical to return then entire list.

You should resolve the causes of Validation errors in dev (Visual Studio) not testing.